# How to set up so on the Mac the default new user will have a single color wallpaper?

Tags: macos, mac, user-account, system-settings

We are trying to set up multiple user accounts on a Mac and wish to have all the users' desktop wallpaper to be single colored (such as aqua blue). It can be done manually but I would like to know if there is a way or script out there so that when a new user is created in "Users & Groups," the default wall paper in that account will be automatically set to a single color.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I know how is to modify the System's "User Template". Here's the steps I used to test on Lion.

1. Use a current account to specify the desktop wallpaper you want. (If
   you use "Solid Colors" there's a button in the lower right to pick a
   custom color.
2. Copy the current account's com.apple.desktop.plist file to the user template:

   ```
   sudo cp ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.desktop.plist /System/Library/User\ Template/Non_localized/Library/Preferences/
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Mac OS X Lion Server has a [profile manager](http://www.apple.com/support/lionserver/profilemanager/) that can assist in pushing settings to both new and existing users. Similarly, you can edit whatever localized versions of the default user template as they are stored in `/System/Library/User Template`. This might be simpler if you prefer to make changes on the machines directly and not bother with setting up a server.